# Using javaFX TableView with scala in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, javafx, javafx-2

When I create a method that return a `TableView` I got something error like this:

[image]

with the error message `class TableView takes type parameter`:

[image]

Comment: I don't know Scala, but, uh, TableView takes a type parameter. Java doesn't insist on them, but apparently Scala does. So you probably need to replace TableView with TableView<T> where T is the type of the object displayed in each row of the table.

Answer (score 3):

TableView takes type parameter. You have to decide which one, based on the type of the values it will hold. Here is what it would look like for Strings:

```
 lazy val tableView = new TableView[String]
```